# Need help with simple linear regressions on many data sets

Tags: regression

We have to predict a future value for one variable based solely on past instances of that variable.   This has to be done for many different data sets, and different formulas can be used for different data sets.   We've been using Excel Trend and Average.   For example, taking the most recent 8 data points, dropping the min and max values, and trending the remaining 6 points has worked well for some data sets.

Any general advice or suggestions for what we might try?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Are these trends over time (eg, price of a stock tomorrow given the prices over the past month), or future values for different units based on the relationship observed in the past (eg, height of a son given father's height given the typical relationship b/t father-son heights we've seen before)?

Comment: These are trends over time - as in how many units sold at specific sites. We have to predict for many sites, and presently we have to estimate future sales for each site, with no other data except past performance for sales at that site. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think what you want is [tag:forecasting] based on a [tag:time-series], possibly with Excel. Those keywords might help you (you might try [searching CV](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=[forecasting]+excel)). If you are really unfamiliar w/ all of this, your question will require more than can be provided here. I believe this is *possible* to do in Excel, but not worth it; you probably should learn other software (such as R) as well. All of these things are learnable w/ enough time & effort, but you may benefit from working with a statistical consultant.

Comment: If you are finding linear trends work okay, you might consider double exponential smoothing. On a more general note, the free book on forecasting by Hyndman and Athana­sopou­los ([*Forecasting: principles and practice*](http://www.otexts.org/fpp/)) useful.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks very much!   Downloaded book and we will try out smoothing.

Answer (score 0):

R would be useful for iterating over many datasets.

```
#Reading Files
myFiles <- list.files(pattern="data.*csv")
for(i in 1:length(myFiles)){
 d=read.csv(myFiles[i])
 #Delete max and min values
 d$v[d$v < max(d$v)]
     d$v[d$v < min(d$v)]
 #Linear Regression
 reg=lm(v~.,data=d)
 #...Etc.
}
```